# Haskell - type definition

Tags: haskell

I got 2 types

```
type Rotor = String 
type Reflector =[(Char, Char)]
```

and I know `type SimpleEnigma` has exactly 3 `Rotor` and 1 `Reflector`. How can I define `SimpleEnigma`?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data SimpleEnigma = SimpleEnigma Rotor Rotor Rotor Reflector
```

We use the `data` keyword to define a new algebraic data type that holds three values of type `Rotor` and one value of type `Reflector`.

Note that you change the name of the value constructor (`SimpleEnigma` to the right of the equal) to something other than `SimpleEnigma` and change the order of types `Rotor` and `Reflector`.

Comment: Why do we need the `SimpleEnigma` to the right of the equal and if I use this type, what does it return?

Comment: `SimpleEnigma` to the left is a type. `SimpleEnigma` to the right is a value constructor: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types

Comment: The `type` keyword introduces a type alias, whereas the `data` constructor introduces new ADTs.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#data and https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#type should be helpful.

Comment: @mnoronha You know the `Maybe` type? It's defined as `data Maybe t = Just t | Nothing` i.e. `Maybe t` is the type itself (on the left) and `Just t` and `Nothing` define the possible values of that type.